# What is the difference between <C-C> and <C-[> in vim?

Tags: vim

One of the best tips for using vim that I have learned so far has been that one can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> instead of the <kbd>Esc</kbd> key. However I use a dvorak keyboard so <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> is a little out of reach for me as well so I mostly use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>. Now I've read somewhere that these two key combinations don't actually have exactly the same behaviour and that it is better to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>. I haven't come across any problems so far though so I'd like to know what exactly is the difference between the two?

Answer (score 15):

According to Vim's documentation, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> does not check for abbreviations and does not trigger the `InsertLeave` autocommand event while <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd> does.

One option is to use the following to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>

```
inoremap <C-c> <Esc><Esc>
```

Comment: `inoremap <C-c> <Esc><Esc>` is a valid syntax, `[...]` is not.

Comment: say, why do you need 2 escapes?

Comment: @doubleDown : to avoid the delay... vim <Esc> waits timeoutlen milliseconds for another char just in case there is a mapping with esc

Answer (score 4):

Extremely late answer, but I just had the same question and found one practical example which helps explain the difference, so why not.

If you select a visual block and then change it with `c` or append something to the end of it with `A`, if you then exit with `<Esc>`, the same change will happen on all the lines of the visual block (which is really useful! See `:help v_b_A`); if you exit with `<C-c>`, this doesn't happen, only one line gets the change. There are probably other similar things I didn't realize I was missing with `<C-c>`...

Comment: Aye, and I just noticed that https://github.com/myusuf3/numbers.vim/ relies on the `Esc` key.

Comment: Another difference is when you are at the opened command window(`q:` from normal mode or `<C-f>` from command mode). In that mode, `<C-[>` will just go out from insert/visual mode(like `<Esc>`), while `<C-c>` will get you back to command mode.

Answer (score 1):

As it turns out, `<C-[>` is exactly identical to Esc, they are the same character. So no need to wonder about any difference there. :)

Comment: The question is asking about the difference between C-[ and C-C though, *not* the difference between C-[ and Esc