# I'm using vim editor and my escape button stopped working. I've some unsaved data and I'm in insert mode. How can I still save my data?

Tags: vim

Getting my content saved.

I want my content saved or written without using the escape button.

I'm worried as my data will not be saved.

Answer (score 5):

Try <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>[</kbd>, which is equivalent to Escape in most terminals.

Answer (score 5):

`<C-c>` and `<C-[>` can both be used instead of `<Esc>`.

Comment: Good point on C-c, but try the other one first, as C-c is [a bit more brute force](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030164/whats-the-difference-between-ctrlc-and-ctrl).

Answer (score 3):

#### "Easy mode" / `'insertmode`'

You can use `<c-l>` to get to normal mode in case you accidentally set `'insertmode'`.

#### `<c-]>` / `<c-c>`

Just as @hobbs and @romainl said, you can always use `<c-]>` (preferred) / `<c-c>` to exit to normal mode. `<c-]>` is the same terminal sequence as `<esc>`, but `<c-c>` will exit to normal mode but will also not execute `InsertLeave`.

#### `<c-o>`

`<c-o>` will put you in normal mode for 1 command then re-enter insert mode.

#### `<c-\><c-n>`

Pretty much will exit to normal mode from any other mode except Ex-mode. It will even exit form Terminal-mode, but only for 1 command.

For more help see:

```
:h 'insertmode'
:h i_CTRL-L
:h CTRL-C
:h i_CTRL-O
:h CTRL-\_CTRL-N
```