# Keyboard shortcuts for Copy/Paste disabled when using vim extension

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VisualStudioCode with the extension VsCodeVim Version 1.10.2.

<kbd>Ctrl + v</kbd> is mapped to select region and I don't know what <kbd>Ctrl + c</kbd> does. It does not change the copy buffer, because when I paste into another application, it pastes the ??previous?? clipboard contents.

I was able to copy/paste with the Edit-Menu and Right-Click menu. So my question is:

How can the keyboard shortcuts for copy/paste be accessed/enabled?

Answer (score 3):

Adding the following lines to your *settings.json* disables the handling of <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl + X</kbd> by VsCodeVim.

```
"vim.handleKeys": {
    "<C-c>": false,
    "<C-v>": false,
    "<C-x>": false,
},
```

Without these lines <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> works for me when selecting words via 'VISUAL' mode. I can now use <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> to paste the clipboard into any other editor. Or I can use <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + V</kbd> to paste into VsCode Editor without entering 'INSERT' mode.
But when in 'INSERT' mode <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> will not work, since <kbd>Ctrl + C</kbd> [will normally abort any commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5036294/5893316). <kbd>Ctrl + V</kbd> on the other Hand works as usual.

---

*Note: I tested this with [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) Version  1.38.1 and [VsCodeVim](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vscodevim.vim) Version 1.10.2*

Comment: Thanks, I will try this...  and even google visual mode.

Comment: Pressing _V_ will enter the VISUAL mode. You are then able to select with the navigation keys. You can also use combinations, like _4e, 2j, ..._ . ESC will leave the VISUAL mode.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be in INSERT mode, for Ctrl-Shift-v to paste.

From normal mode, Ctrl-v enters block visual mode, if you want char or line visual mode you use v and Shift-v respectively...  Then presumably copy and cut with Ctrl-Shift-(c/x) would work.

Alternatively you can try [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58116261/1153319) suggestion.

Comment: This is still very difficult to pull off, much can be improved.