# Exit insert mode by Ctrl+C

Tags: vim

Let's say I have file that contains only this strings:

```
This strings
need to be commented
```

While in normal mode I execute this chain of commands:

<kbd>g</kbd><kbd>g</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd><kbd>j</kbd><kbd>I</kbd><kbd>/</kbd><kbd>/</kbd>

And now, if I push <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> I'll have this

```
//This strings
need to be commented
```

but if I push <kbd>Esc</kbd> I'll have this

```
//This strings
//need to be commented
```

Why do the results differ?

Comment: Which version of vim are you using ? I am unable to reproduce this. For me <c-c> behaves just like <Esc> and i_^c isn't mapped in my env.

Comment: Answer at [What is the difference between <C-C> and <C-[> in vim?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/80677).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to help for `i_Ctrl-c`, when quitting normal mode by <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, vim doesn't trigger `InsertLeave` event which as I think finishes insertions.

Workaround for this is to remap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to <kbd>Esc</kbd>

```
noremap <C-c> <Esc>
```

Comment: Perhaps best to do that mapping only in insert mode. `inoremap...`

Comment: It should be noted that `<esc>` and `<c-c>` are not equivalent. However `<c-[>` is equivalent to `<esc>`.

Comment: @progo, for only insert mode it's better to use `inoremap` but I don't see any problems setting this behavior for all modes.

Comment: @black_wizard: could be nothing, but I was thinking of cancelling a long-running command. Perhaps it'll work with the binding in the mode, or not.