# Check if Vim is editing a remote file or a local file with Vimscript

Tags: vim

I've been using Vim for a while now, but mostly in a local context, and I did

```
inoremap kj <C-c>:w<CR>
```

in my `.vimrc` so that <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>j</kbd> will exit insert mode as well as save the file, which helps boost my speed with Vim a lot.

Recently I started to need to edit remote files via FTP with Vim, and as you must have guessed, it takes much longer to write files from my local buffer to the remote server. I can tweak my `.vimrc` file to not save the file when exiting insert mode with <kbd>k</kbd><kbd>j</kbd>, but that's too much trouble editing back and forth.

So is it possible to somehow write a function with Vimscript, so that my Vim behaves as described with pseudo-code below?

```
if (Vim is editing a local file):
    inoremap kj <C-c>:w<CR>
else if (Vim is editing a remote file with any protocol):
    inoremap kj <C-c>
```

Comment: Can you try checking for `b:netrw_method` and `b:netrw_fname`? `netrw` should define and set them when accessing files remotely, but I can't verify that at the moment.

Comment: Ensure that you really need [Ctrl-c instead of Esc](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80677/). Also consider using `updadte` instead of `write`.

Comment: @MichaelFoukarakis no, those two are not defined in my buffer.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you use netrw or another FTP client, the file you edit is downloaded to a temporary location, edited and re-uploaded back upon write.

What you need to do is find where the temporary file is downloaded and write an `autocmd`.

Assuming the temporary file's path is `/temp/ftpclient/121354/file.html`, you could write something like:

```
inoremap kj <C-c>:w<CR>
augroup quickescape
    autocmd!
    augroup BufRead,BufNew /temp/**/* inoremap <buffer> kj <C-c>
augroup END
```

Comment: I just added this to my `.vimrc` and it behaved exactly as before. Help me work through this if you don't mind: what does that `quickescape` mean? And what exactly does `BufRead,BufNew` do? I know they are `autocmd` events, so I assume it means whenever I load to buffer a file with path in the form of `/tmp/**/*` (which in my case is where the temp file located), it maps `kj` to <C-c> for the current buffer? But why doesn't it work?

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the file name begins with a protocol using `expand('%') =~ '\m\C^\(dav\|fetch\|ftp\|http\|rcp\|rsync\|scp\|sftp\|file\)://'`.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but I solved the problem. Here's the code snippet I used:

```
" just call this function in your mapping
function Write()
  let s = expand("%:p") " gets the full filename
  if s =~ "^ftp://" " checks whether filename starts with ftp://
    " do command on ftp file
  else
    " do command for normal file
  endif
endfunction
```